# did not compile my poyect in linux react-native compile exit

Tags: android, linux, react-native

I'm trying to compile a react-native project in linux, the project does compile 100% but at the time of connecting to the phone it leaves the compilation, any idea?

[image]

and my phone dials me in that it can't be connected.

Comment: whats the error you got?

Comment: anyone... in pc... anyone, but in mobile didn't conect with server ... because imediatly when the compilation finish.... the compilation exit.